# executing a subprocess from python

Tags: python, subprocess, vlc

I think something is getting subtly mangeled when I attempt to execute a subprocess from a python script

I attempt to execute vlc with some (a lot) of arguments.

the instance of vlc that arises complains:

> Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL ' -vvv rtsp://192.168.1.201:554/ch0_multicast_one --sout=#transcode{acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:5544/user_hash.sdp},dst=display} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep'. Check the log for details.

Here is the python code

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["vlc "," -vvv rtsp://%s" % target_nvc.ip_address + ":554/ch0_multicast_one --sout=#transcode{acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:5544/user_hash.sdp},dst=display} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep" ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I have examined the output of the subprocess function (using a shell), and if I copy paste that string into my cmd window, the vlc instance works fine... Is this a privilege thing?

Comment: What does the log say? the error message looks like it couldn't parse the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this...

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["vlc", "-vvv", 
    "rtsp://%s" % target_nvc.ip_address + ":554/ch0_multicast_one", 
    "--sout=#transcode{acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:5544/user_hash.sdp},dst=display}", 
    ":no-sout-rtp-sap", ":no-sout-standard-sap", 
    ":ttl=1", ":sout-keep" ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: derp! Ok that totally works, but now my vlc instance doesn't start until after i kill the runserver. can I break the sub process out on its own?

Comment: @michael, I'm not sure whether it matters but for the record, which python are you using?  Cygwin, ActiveState or Python.org for windows?

Comment: I wonder if I be looking into invoking a thread instead of a sub process. That way its non-blocking but i can still manage it...

Comment: @michael, that could help... I'm installing python for windows now so I can test without threads... I'm not sure how windows spawns things... fyi, I'm using windows 7

Comment: Exact behavior: I have django runserver running locally (win 7). From the webpage, I click on a link that causes a python func with the vlc invoking code to run. The vlc instance won't pop up (although I can see it in the task manager) until i kill the runserver. The runserver will not fully restart until I kill the vlc instance.

Comment: @michael, when I spawn with `Popen(['C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/vlc/vlc'], stdout = PIPE, stdin = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)` under windows 7, it spends about 5 seconds loading and then starts vlc without blocking.  I'm using python 2.7.1... perhaps some of your CLI switches are doing something?  Could you try spawning vlc without the CLI switches and see if that matters?

Comment: I got it to work by dumping the extra arguments sent to Popen. I will have to go back to those and see what they were and if i need them in the long run, but for now...good enough. Thanks!

Comment: @michael, thank you for the update.  I think the most productive thing you could do is try to execute the same CLI that blocks from the msdos command line.  Then ensure that everything delimited by a space in your CLI is a separate entry in the list that is passed to `Popen()`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're passing a *list* to `subprocess.Popen`, each parameter must be in its *own* element. So you'd want something like:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen([
    "vlc",
    "-vvv",
    "rtsp://%s:554/ch0_multicast_one" % target_nvc.ip_address,
    # etc
], ...)
```

Each parameter (that the shell would normally parse apart for you) must be in a separate list element.

You can also pass a single command line string and let the shell pull it apart:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen("vlc -vvv rtsp://...", shell=True, ...)
```

Using the first form is better for commands that have lots of arguments.

Comment: You can't pass a single string unless you also pass `shell=True`.
`>>> Popen('echo Hello')`
`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

```py
movies_path = glob.glob("D:\\MOVIES\**\*\*\*.mp4", recursive=True) + \
              glob.glob("D:\\MOVIES\**\*\*\*.mkv", recursive=True) + \
              glob.glob("D:\\MOVIES\**\*\*\*.avi", recursive=True)

# probably the right movie
rightMoviePath = difflib.get_close_matches(which_movie, movies_path, len(movies_path), 0)
movie_name = rightMoviePath[0].split("\\")[-1]
hebrew_subtitle_path = glob.glob(rightMoviePath[0].replace(movie_name, "Hebrew.srt"))[0]
english_subtitle_path = glob.glob(rightMoviePath[0].replace(movie_name, "English.srt"))[0]

process, player = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Users\\yonat\\Downloads\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "--sub-file", hebrew_subtitle_path, rightMoviePath[0]],
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```